# check http connection vbscript

Tags: http, vbscript, connection

I need to check http connection with vbscript

I thought to ping to the host and  to see if the host responds

I need to test the connection to a specific port and why not also with a url

do you have a solution?

Comment: Search and you shall find. [This was asked yesterday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028355/check-network-connection-with-vbscript/31029296)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,strHost
Title = "Check Connection"
strHost = "www.stackoverflow.com"
if Ping(strHost) = True then
    MsgBox "Host " & DblQuote(strHost) & " contacted",vbInformation,Title
Else
    MsgBox "Host " & DblQuote(strHost) & " could not be contacted",vbCritical,Title
end if
'***********************************************************************************
Function Ping(strHost)
    dim objPing, objRetStatus
    set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery _
      ("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    for each objRetStatus in objPing
        if IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 then
        Ping = False
            'WScript.Echo "Status code is " & objRetStatus.StatusCode
        else
            Ping = True
            'Wscript.Echo "Bytes = " & vbTab & objRetStatus.BufferSize
            'Wscript.Echo "Time (ms) = " & vbTab & objRetStatus.ResponseTime
            'Wscript.Echo "TTL (s) = " & vbTab & objRetStatus.ResponseTimeToLive
        end if
    next
End Function 
'***********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I need to check http connection with a specific port on my url

Comment: Take a look at this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010631/command-line-for-looking-at-specific-port

Comment: And this in powershell ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message

Answer (score 1):

I'm inspired by this ==> [How to check Network port access and display useful message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message)

And i created a vbscript wrapped with the powershell script

Just give a try :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Ws,ByPassPSFile,strHost,Example,PSFile,MyCmd,Result,MyArray,LogFile,fso
Title = "Check Network port access "
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "txt"
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /c PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Example = "www.google.com:80"
strHost = InputBox("Enter the host name with its port to check it " & vbcr & "Example : " & vbcr & Dblquote(Example) & "",Title,Example)
If strHost = "" or IsEmpty(strHost) Then Wscript.Quit()
MyArray = Split(strHost,":")
MyCmd = "function Test-Port($hostname,$port)"& VbCrLF &_
"{"& VbCrLF &_
    "# This works no matter in which form we get $host - hostname or ip address" & VbCrLF &_
    "try {"& VbCrLF &_
       "$ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($hostname) |"& VbCrLF &_ 
         "select-object IPAddressToString -expandproperty  IPAddressToString"& VbCrLF &_
        "if($ip.GetType().Name -eq ""Object[]"")"& VbCrLF &_
        "{"& VbCrLF &_
            "#If we have several ip's for that address, let's take first one"& VbCrLF &_
           "$ip = $ip[0]"& VbCrLF &_
        "}"& VbCrLF &_
    "} catch {"& VbCrLF &_
       "return ""Possibly $hostname is wrong hostname or IP"""& VbCrLF &_
    "}"& VbCrLF &_
    "$t = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient"& VbCrLF &_
    "# We use Try\Catch to remove exception info from console if we can't connect"& VbCrLF &_
    "try"& VbCrLF &_
    "{"& VbCrLF &_
        "$t.Connect($ip,$port)"& VbCrLF &_
    "} catch {}"& VbCrLF &_
    "if($t.Connected)"& VbCrLF &_
    "{"& VbCrLF &_
        "$t.Close()"& VbCrLF &_
        "$msg = ""Port $port is operational on $hostname with ip adress $ip"""& VbCrLF &_
    "}"& VbCrLF &_
    "else"& VbCrLF &_
    "{"& VbCrLF &_
        "$msg = ""Port $port on $hostname with ip $ip is closed, """& VbCrLF &_
        "$msg += ""You may need to contact your IT team to open it."""& VbCrLF &_         
    "}"& VbCrLF &_
    "return $msg"& VbCrLF &_
"}"& VbCrLF &_
"Test-Port "& MyArray(0) & " "& MyArray(1) & " > "& LogFile &""& VbCrLF
Call WriteMyPSFile(MyCmd)
Result = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
ws.run LogFile
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteMyPSFile(strText)
Dim fs,ts,PSFile
Const ForWriting = 2
    PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```